# Simple inquality for tail sums and probability

Tags: probability, summation

Given $K>0$ how do I show that:
$$
\sum_{n\geq0}P(T>n)\leq K \sum_{n\geq0}P(T>nK)
$$

I have tried to write out the sums to get a feeling but still could not work out how to show this... Doesn't K need to be a non-negative integer?

Comment: $K\sum_{n\geq0}P(T>nK)=KP(T>0)+KP(T>1K)+KP(T>2K)+... =P(T>0)+P(T>0)+...+P(T>0)+P(T>K)+...+P)T>K)+... \geq P(T>0)+P(T>1)+...+P(T>K-1)+P(T>K)+...+P(T>2K-1)+...=\sum_{n \geq 0}P(T>n)$

Comment: Thank you @mathpadawan but I do not understand why the penultimate inequality or the last equality holds... :( how do you get the $P(T>1)$ in there?

Comment: The event $T>Kn$ includes the event $T>Kn+i \forall i \geq 0$. I guess the last equality is by definition?

Comment: Top, get it. So if $K$ positive but let's say very small, there comes a point where $1/K$ is a pretty big number so those two multiplied give the 1 and than so on. Thank you very much!

Comment: But then the K before the sum is not really needed right?

Comment: I am sorry to bother you but for example if we insert K=2 there. Does it still hold? On the right side we would only have "half" the summ of the left side right? This is bothering me...

Comment: for k=2, $2P(T>0)=P(T>0)+P(T>0) \geq P(T>0)+P(T>1)$. And then $2P(T>2)=P(T>2)+P(T>2) \geq P(T>2)+P(T>3)$ and so on?

Comment: Ah that's dope, thank you so much!